# When creating a new record, create the nested records as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

When creating a new `Musician`, I also need to create a set of `ItemLevels`.

`ItemLevel` is polymorphic and also `has_many :levels`.

`Levels` just stores the various types of levels available to a musicians (stress, happiness, skill, etc).

`ItemLevel` joins a particular level (ie. stress) to a specific Musician (or Band or Manager...which is why it's polymorphic).

So when a new Musician is created, I need to create all the ItemLevels for that musician. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use callback on your model

`before_save` or `before_create` if you want only run your callback on your create. In this method you can create you levels.